# What do each symbol mean? (For exponentials)

Tags: clicker-heroes

As you know, **Clicker Heroes** is an idle game all about exponential numbers and... A lot of waiting.
However, when the number gets big, they start representing them with symbols and not letters (for example, `500k` = `500,000`), and I'm seeing numbers like `71,668%`.

### Question:

What are the symbols used and their exponential equalivants?
For consistency sake, please also include the metric symbols; `K = kilo` for numbers in thousands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the webversion this is on the right side:

Legend of Large Numbers

1K  =   1,000   =   One Thousand

1M  =   1,000K  =   One Million

1B  =   1,000M  =   One Billion

1T  =   1,000B  =   One Trillion

1q  =   1,000T  =   One Quadrillion

1Q  =   1,000q  =   One Quintillion

1s  =   1,000Q  =   One Sextillion

1S  =   1,000s  =   One Septillion

1O  =   1,000S  =   One Octillion

1N  =   1,000O  =   One Nonillion

1d  =   1,000N  =   One Decillion

1U  =   1,000d  =   One Undecillion

1D  =   1,000U  =   One Duodecillion

1!  =   1,000D  =   One Tredecillion

1@  =   1,000!  =   One Quattuordecillion

1#  =   1,000@  =   One Quindecillion

1$  =   1,000#  =   One Sexdecillion

1%  =   1,000$  =   One Septendecillion

1^  =   1,000%  =   One Octodecillion

1&  =   1,000^  =   One Novemdecillion

1*  =   1,000&  =   One Vigintillion

A lot   >   1,000*  <   A lot

Comment: it looks pretty organized to me, how would you want to change that?

Comment: Actually.. Nevermind... What I was meant to say was: **"Strange. My game doesn't have 1& and up. After 1^, it's 1e+[60-something]"**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick version I keep in a note:

```
1K=103 , 1M=106 , 1B=109 ,  
1T=1012, 1q=1015, 1Q=1018,  
1s=1021, 1S=1024, 1O=1027,  
1N=1030, 1d=1033, 1U=1036,  
1D=1039, 1!=1042, 1@=1045,  
1#=1048, 1$=1051, 1%=1054,  
1^=1057, 1&=1060, 1*=1063
```

I do this because don't find words like "Tredecillion," or knowing the basic sequence, as useful as knowing the order of magnitude.

You can quickly see why no one can easily memorize this list:
K, M, B, T follow metric then U.S. definitions, q:Q and s:S follow each other but d:D do not. O, N, and U don't have a pair. None of these letters are consistently ordered say by alphabet, only the !...* symbols have a knowable order if you use a US keyboard layout.